# Actuator not resolving variables due to Config Server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I have a project using Spring Boot Actuator that's getting its configs from a Spring Config Server.

Last week I took all of the property yamls and moved them to the Config Repo that's on GitHub. So, currently, my project has only `bootstrap{-profile}.yml` on `src/main/resources/` directory.

Everything is working fine, except for `/actuator/info` endpoint. I use the "variables" for getting project name and version at runtime, and since moving this setting to Config Repo it's not being resolved to the real value, but showing the string as the value itself.

bootstrap.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: 'foo'
  profiles: 
     active: default
  cloud:
     config:
       uri: http://localhost:8888
```

foo.yml, on Config Repo:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8090

info:
  app:
    name: "@project.name@"
    version: "@project.version@"

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

This is the response from `/actuator/info`:

```json
{
  "app": {
    "name": "@project.name@",
    "version": "@project.version@"
  }
}
```

This is the expected response:

```json
{
  "app": {
    "name": "foo",
    "version": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

I was suspecting Config Server was to blame, so I moved the `info.app.*` properties to a local `application.yml` in `src/main/resources/` and it was fixed. So it only happens when loading the configs from Config Server.

Am I missing something? Or is this a known issue with Config Server and Actuator? I did some research and could not find the root cause for this, not even someone with the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Properties like `@project.name@` and `@project.version@` are resolved at build time by the Maven or Gradle plugin, not at runtime. This can be done when the `application.yml` file is in the source repository, but a yml file stored in a separate repo for use with Spring Cloud Config Server won't be seen at build time.

This is covered in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-automatic-expansion).

Comment: There's something I didn't know! I really thought this was some Actuator-specific property expansion feature. Thank you very much!

Also, should I expect this to work with `bootstrap.yml` files as well? I remember doing this test and having no success, but maybe it was some lack of attention of mine.

Comment: With Maven, the property replacement is done by the Maven Resources plugin, with configuration applied by Spring Boot. By default only `application*.[yml|yaml|properties]` will be modified. You can override the default behavior with your own configuration in `pom.xml`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/build.gradle#L20-L50 for the Boot defaults.